# ActionLink back button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I have an Index method that does double duty as showing a list of posts and a queried list of posts and can also have pages so you get urls like `/News/Page/1` or `/News?query=test`

When a user clicks through to a post at say `News/Details/1` they get a simple ActionLink that takes them back to the list. BUT I want this link to take them back to the actual page they were on in terms of the paging or the query. How could I do this? I don't want to use the JavaScript history method. Here is my current ActionLink: `<%=Html.ActionLink("<< Back to News List", "Index")%>` and this is an example of the paging links: `<%= Html.RouteLink("<< First Page", "NewsPaging", new { query = ViewData["query"], page = 0 })%>`

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It would probably be easier to just use javascript to send them back to the last page in their history (without creating a link to the specific page).

```
history.go(-1)
```

Answer (score 4):

I will go for a ActionLink like

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("<< Back to News List", "Index")%>
```

because user can access `News/Details/1` directly and if then you have a link that uses `history.go(-1)` or `history.back()` function it will not redirect it to the Index action

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to create the link in the controller and assign it to a property of the model or a simple ViewBag variable (up to you). For this example, I'm just going to use ViewBag.

So in your example, going from `/News/Details/1` back to `/News/Page/1?some-querystring`, you can do the following:

In your controller (assuming '1' is the 'id'):

```
ViewBag.BackButton = String.Format("/News/Page/{0}{1}", id.ToString(), Request.Url.Query);
```

In your view:

```
<a href="@ViewBag.BackButton">&lt; Back</a>
```

One draw back to this is that you must know what the previous page was/could be. In your case, you want your back button to go back to your list, so this technique should be fine.