# Add 'Back Button' on page

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, request, back-button

How to add button "Back to *X-page*", where *X-page* is name of previous page.

I red this post about [Request.UrlReferrer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978129/back-button-or-navigate-to-specific-viewpage-aps-net-mvc3), but don't understand how to get page title.

I try to parse PageRefferrer and is some token exists - i set some name of *X-Page*, but i can't process all cases. Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

```
<script>
    document.write('<a href="' + document.referrer + '">Go Back</a>');
</script>
```

Good luck....

Comment: Hi! Thanks for reply! But i want to display more detailed info about previous page. For example `<a href="' + document.referrer + '">Go Back to My Account</a>` if previous page was 'My Account' and  `<a href="' + document.referrer + '">Go Back to News</a>` if previous page was 'News' etc.

Comment: above solution has the benefit of showing the URL of the linked-to page on hover, as most browsers do by default

Comment: but still... is there another solution?