# on html.actionlink click go to previous page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, html.actionlink

Currently in a link

`Customer/businessunit/RepresentativeDetails?RepresentativeId=cd3a7263-78f7-41bd-9eb0-12b30bc1059a`

I have following code for view

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
```

which takes me to this link

```
customer/businessunit/index
```

but rather that going to index page I want to go to previous page when the actionlink is clicked, which is

```
Customer/businessunit/BusinessUnitDetails/c4a86253-a287-441e-b83d-71fbb6a588bc
```

How do I create an actionlink that directs me to previous page?
something like `@Html.ActionLink("Back to Details", //go to previous page)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActionLink back button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686124/actionlink-back-button)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Unless you're tracking what the previous page is on the server, why not just use the browser's internal history?  In that case there wouldn't be a need for server-side code.  You could just use something like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="history.go(-1);">Back to Details</a>
```

Or, separating the code from the markup:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="backLink">Back to Details</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '#backLink', function () {
        history.go(-1);
    });
</script>
```

This would send the user back to whatever was the last page in their browser history.  (Of course, if they reached that page from any other source then it wouldn't take them "back to details" but instead just "back".)

Comment: I have very rare case , my app consist with two parts blog and main part, blog is written in mvc , main app is written in agular+api, when i go from my angular app to the mvc app and then press back button from browser, page does not refresshed.  Can you pleaese give me some idea how can i solve this?

Answer (score 47):

If you still want to use `ActionLink` you can do something like as suggested by [JuanPieterse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17990164/3222478)

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to previous page", null, null, null, new { href = Request.UrlReferrer})
```

You can use `action` in `controller` too. See answers to similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/815229/3222478)

Answer (score 13):

Don't use ActionLink for this... just do:

`<a href="javascript:history.back()">Back to List</a>`

...which will take the user back to wherever they were prior to the current page

Comment: I have very rare case , my app consist with two parts blog and main part, blog is written in mvc , main app is written in agular+api, when i go from my angular app to the mvc app and then press back button from browser, page does not refresshed.  Can you pleaese give me some idea how can i solve this?

Answer (score 12):

If you don't like to use `ActionLink` or JavaScript, the `href="@Request.UrlReferrer"` will do the trick:

```
<div>
    <a href="@Request.UrlReferrer" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" title="Back to list">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant.  The best answer here IMO.  Simple.  No inline JS or odd looking `ActionLink`.

Comment: On refresh page  @Request.UrlReferre = null

Comment: I have very rare case , my app consist with two parts blog and main part, blog is written in mvc , main app is written in agular+api, when i go from my angular app to the mvc app and then press back button from browser, page does not refresshed.  Can you pleaese give me some idea how can i solve this?

Answer (score 2):

This is quite a bit after the fact, but I thought I'd contribute. Personally, I would tag my markup elements with a CSS class so I could just reuse the tag and be done with it.

Markup:

```
<a href="" class="go_back"> Back </a>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.go_back').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            history.go(-1);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ActionLink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("بازگشت", null, null, null, new { href = Request.UrlReferrer })
```

Comment: How is this answer different from the one provided by "aim" on Feb 16' 15?

Answer (score 0):

i know this is too late but i got this answer.

```
<button type='reset' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='window.location.go(-1);'><i class='fa fa-ban'></i> Cancel </button></div>
```